# Buffer Overflow into a different exe's memory? Or onto csrss.exe from a remote desktop prog?

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, memory-management, buffer-overflow

**Short, Question Form:**

I did some googling but wasn't able to come up with the answer to this: is it possible to buffer overflow memory into another exe's memory?  And/or, is it possible to overflow csrss.exe's memory from an exe running on a remote desktop session?

**Longer Story - Here's Our Situation:**

We've got a server with an always-running remote desktop session that has a 24/7 program running - a C++ .exe.  To make things worse, the C++ exe was programmed using all sorts of unsafe memory operations (raw strcpy, sprintf, etc)  You don't need to tell me how bad this is structurally - I completely agree.

Recently, our server's been having Blue Screen Of Death, and the dumpfile is indicating that csrss.exe is being terminated by our C++ exe (which will cause a BSOD, and csrss.exe is also responsible for managing remote desktop sessions.

So I wanted to know if anyone knew whether it was possible for one app to do a memory buffer overflow that overflowed onto another app's memory space, or whether it'd be possible for an app on a remote desktop session to do so onto csrss.exe?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer no it is not.

Simplified explanation of why. Each program runs in it's own virtual address space. This virtual address space is controlled by the page table which is essentially a lookup table to map virtual addresses (the addresses in the pointers of the executable) onto physical memory addresses. When the OS switches to a task it hands the correct table to the cpu/core running the task. Any physical address not mentioned in this table will not be accessible from the program. Physical addresses belonging to another application should not appear in this table so it would be impossible to access memory belonging to another application. When a program misbehaves and accesses invalid memory location it will attempt to use virtual addresses not mentioned in the table. This will trigger an exception/fault on the cpu which is normally reported in windows as an "Access violation".

Of course the OS and the CPU can contain bugs so it is impossible to guarantee that it doesn't happen. But if your C++ program misbehaves then still most of the time this would be caught by the CPU and reported as an access violation and not result in a BSOD. If you do not see your C++ program generating access violations I would expect it to be much more likely that the problem is caused by faulty memory or a buggy driver (drivers run at a higher privilege and can do things normal programs can't).

I would say start with doing an extensive memory test with a program like memtest86. BTW if the server is a "real" server with ECC memory, faulty memory shouldn't be the problem as this should have been reported by the system.

**Update**
Doesn't matter how the memory access happens underflow, overflow, uninitialized pointer. The virtual address used is either mapped to a physical memory location reserved for the program or it is not mapped at all. BTW the checking is done by the CPU the OS only maintains the tables used to do the lookups.

However this doesn't mean every error by the program will be detected because as long as it is accessing addresses for which it was assigned memory the access is ok as far as the CPU is concerned. The heap manager in your program might think otherwise but has no way of detecting this. So even a buffer overflow at the end of the address space doesn't always cause an access violation because memory is assigned to the program in pages of atleast 4kB and the heap manager subdivides those pages into the smaller chunks the program asks it for. So your small 10 byte buffer can be at the start of such a page and writing a thousand bytes to it will be perfectly fine as far as the cpu is concerned. Because all that memory was setup for use by the program. However when your 10 byte buffer is at the end of the page and the next entry is not assigned to a physical address location an access violation will occur.

Comment: Question about the 'why' portion: does that also hold true if it's a buffer overflow situation?  In other words, if I allocate a 10-byte slot of memory near the very end of the exe's memory space, and try to write 1000 bytes to it, does the OS check that?  My worry is that an sprintf() or strcpy() statement is trying to copy 1000+ bytes to a char[100] or something, and is overflowing onto another app's memory space.

Comment: @Kevin:  Yes, memory protection works even in the case of a buffer overflow.  The memory of other processes will be protected, and the buffer overflow can only damage the program with the bug.

Comment: Thanks!  Okay, one final angle on the question: does anything in the picture change if the first .exe is running on a remote desktop session, and the second .exe is the one responsible for remote desktop (csrss.exe)?

Comment: Not really csrss.exe is listed as a user mode portion of windows which should mean that it runs as a normal user program just like your c++ program. It could be that it the OS grants is some special rights but that would mean it could write over memory owned by your application not the other way around.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for your help, everyone!